# Is it possible to Bind the DataContext of a UserControl to a property

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a user control that I would like to use in two different contexts.  The user control needs its DataContext set to an instance of an appropriate ViewModel that has been created by the parent view/viewmodel.

I was hoping for something like:

```
<local:Child DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
```

where ChildViewModel is a inpc-styled property of the ViewModel that the page is bound to.

That doesn't seem to work.  Is it possible to assign the DataContext by using Binding?

Comment: Could you provide entries from Output Window? Basically, all wpf binding exceptions are shown there, so if you have one, we will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be simpler to bind the Content of an ContentControl to your child ViewModel like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />
```

..and then have a DataTemplate to apply your local:Child View, like this

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ChildViewModel}">
    <local:Child />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, however being tagged a silverlight question, this solution won't work.

Comment: Drop the DataType property on the DataTemplate and this should then work in Silverlight.