# Is it possible to bind code-behind property without setting DataContext?

Tags: wpf, xaml

As titled, 
I seen couples of similiar question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994595/is-it-possible-to-bind-the-datacontext-of-a-usercontrol-to-a-property) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102453/how-to-bind-to-a-local-property-in-silverlight-without-using-a-datacontext) in SO, but I don't see a solution for it.

I know if I need to bind to the code-beind, I need to set `Datacontext = this`

But my problem is that my datacontext already binding to my ViewModel, but I want to do some UI manipulation with using Command which is defined in the code-beind.

Is it possbile to bind it in xaml? If so, how?

EDIT: I did tried the follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="_Root">
<Grid x:Name="hellogrid">
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="AAAA"/>
    <Button Margin="82,119,121,120" Name="button2" Content="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=myTextBlock}"/>
    <Button Margin="82,72,121,0" Name="button3" Content="{Binding Path=MyText, ElementName=_Root}" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

And code-behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyText = "ABC";
    }
}
```

I could see the Button2 shows `AAAA`, but Button3 shows nothing....

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I just tested and the way you bind your button3 Content property works fine, you just need to implement change notification if you need to change that MyText property at run time...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT**

The best solution IMO is the one [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022711/229930) by @Saad Imran in this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705322/wpf-binding-objects-defined-in-codebehind)...

With this solution all you have to do is name your window and binding to a property in your XAML will be as easy as this `{Binding ElementName=MyWindowName, Path=MyText}`

So, what you are doing with `Content="{Binding Path=MyText, ElementName=_Root}"` is exactly right and your Button Content property IS bound to MyText property but the only thing you are missing is change notification (need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for that) so when you set your MyText property to ABC `MyText = "ABC";` no change notification is sent...

Easy way to test this is by setting the MyText property explicitly as such:

```
private string myText = "ABC";
public string MyText
{
   get { return myText; }
   set { myText = value; }
}
```

or setting it in the constructor before `InitializeComponent()` is called:

```
MyText = "ABC";
InitializeComponent();
```

If you do that you'll notice that your button will have ABC as its content but changes to MyText property will not affect the button content because there is no change notification...

Comment: Ahhh, I see, that's why I have been missing.  It works prefect now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17):

Of course

There are many types of bindings. The most basic one binds to a property on the `DataContext`, which is usually inherited from a Parent object

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyModel}">
    <!-- DataContext is object of type MyModel -->
    <local:MyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Or

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow">
    <!-- DataContext Inherited from Window -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" /> 
</Window>
```

where

```cs
var SomeObject = new SomeModel();
SomeObject.SomeProperty = "Test";
myWindow.DataContext = SomeObject;
```

Other binding types include `ElementName`, where you can specify the target UI element to use as the data source for the binding

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="SomeCheckBox" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
</StackPanel>
```

or

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="SomeUserControl">
    <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=SomeUserControl, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" />
</local:MyUserControl >
```

Or `RelativeSource`, which allows you to find an object relative to the current object to use as a DataSource

```
<Window Title="Test">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Title}" />
</Window>
```

or

```
<local:MyUserControl>
    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}" />
</local:MyUserControl >
```

And `TemplateBinding`, which binds is a shortcut to a `RelativeSource` binding that binds to a templated object

```
<Button Content="Test">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your referece! I got it working with your RelativeSource too.  But strange, how come I don't need INotifyPropertyChanged when I use `RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}`?

Comment: @DeanKuga I was unclear of what the actual question was at first before the code was added, and read it as "can I bind to something without specifying it in the DataContext". It seemed a bit of a broad question, so I wrote a broad answer :) Once the code got added, I could clearly see what OP was trying to accomplish, but by then an answer had already been posted containing the information he needed.

Comment: @Rachel When should I use a binding with an element name which is binding to the window with window's name and when should I use the binding with the RelativeSource? It seems like they're doing the same thing

Comment: @YonatanNir Usually I prefer using `ElementName` bindings if possible because they're easier to understand, but sometimes you have to bind to an unnamed element further up the visual tree. A common example would be an item in a `ListBoxItemTemate` needing to bind the the `ListBoxItem` it's a part of. Typically a `ListBox` is bound, so the `ListBoxItems` are autogenerated and don't have a name, so a `RelativeSoruce` binding is commonly used there instead

Answer (score 8):

Sure, you can use [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx):

```
<Window Name="root"
        Class="..."
        ...>

    ...

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Foo, ElementName=root}" />
```

You could also do it with [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx), but the syntax is uglier...

Comment: Strange, I did try both `ElementName` and `Binding Path=Foo, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, but both doesn't work. I am using WPF 3.5, does it matter?

Comment: @KingChan, it's because you set the MyText property *after* the call to `InitializeComponent`, so the value has already been retrieved before you change it. Since your class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and your property isn't a dependency property, the binding engine has no way of knowing the value has changed, so it doesn't refresh the button's content.